# Flex 4 Inline htmlText Bullet Styling

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is it possible to style the following so that I can replace the bullet with an image.

```
                                    <mx:Text width="100%">
                                    <mx:htmlText>
                                        <![CDATA[<ul><li>Item 0</li><br /><li>Item 1</li><br /><li>Item 2</li></ul>]]>
                                    </mx:htmlText>
                                </mx:Text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is should be possible with TLF 2.0, preferably with Flex 4.5 SDK

Example
http://www.justinpante.net/?p=213